# move_uploaded_file(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I try to insert images in my database with PHP and MySQL with a temporary folder.

**I use laravel and this is my controller:**

```
if(isset($_FILES['img_masc']))
{
    $img=$_FILES['img_masc']['name'];
    $ruta= $_FILES['img_masc']['tmp_name'];
}

$destino='../../../Perf_Masc/'.$img;
$masc->img=$destino;
//copy($ruta, $destino);
move_uploaded_file($ruta, $destino); //line 49
```

**This is my view:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/RegMasc" enctype= "multipart/form-data" >
    <div>
        <input required name="img_masc" type="file"/>
    </div>
```

**This is my error:**

> ErrorException in line 49:
>   move_uploaded_file(../../../Perf_Masc/AF5.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I try with so much things and also with the copy function and is not working anyway

Comment: Try to add full path and then check

Comment: Do you have any folders like Perf_Masc on right destination?

Comment: try  $destino= $img; and see if file saved at the same place where you have the php file

Comment: try to debug. check if the dir really exists using `file_exists('../../../Perf_Masc/');`

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Config file or some common file define your path as below

`define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'<YOUR PROJECT DIRECTORY>/');`

Include this common php in all your class file.

Then

```
 $destino= DOCROOT.'Perf_Masc/'.$img; // HERE DOCROOT is defined in config.
```

Comment: I put the define('DOCROOT', 'D:/wamp/www/total/'); in the top of the function where i am using the image stuff is that correct?

Because that way doesn't work D: 

throw me this error now:

move_uploaded_file(C:/wamp/www/total/Perf_Masc/AF5.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @Valeria `total` is my project name. You replace your project directory name

Comment: Ohhh, i understand but if all my project is in 'C:/wamp/www/' how i write that? S: i am sorry but i am learning yet. D:

Comment: C:/wamp/www/<YOUR PROJECT DIRECTORY>/

Comment: @Valeria refer my updated answer. In this way you need not to modify your codings when migrate server

Comment: All the folders of my project are in C:/wamp/www/ because i use laravel and laravel pull apart the project in controllers, views and models, i dont have clear how i supposed to do that, so please be patience with me i'm learning

Comment: @Valeria you mean to say you dont have any separate project folders? all your laravel folders inside `wamp/www`? Directory `Perf_Masc/` is inside `wamp/www/`

Comment: Yep that's right D: because i start quicly the project and i am new in laravel.

Comment: @Valeria then define as `define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` and then `$destino=DOCROOT.'Perf_Masc/'.$img;`

Comment: OMG thank you very much longer functions properly.
Can you explain how? Only a little?.
thanks anyway. :DD

Comment: @Valeria before `move_upload_file()` doesn't find the destination directory. I mean `../../../Perf_Masc` doesn't meant the right path.

Comment: Hmmm... but i try with more paths and nothing works.
And now if you can help me with something else, i can't show the image in my page u_u

echo('<img src="');echo($img_masc); echo('" width="250px" border-radius="1000px"/> '); 

$img_masc it's the address where the image is.

Comment: @Valeria what is not working? Upload is not working or image uploaded but not displating properly?

Comment: The path of the image is correctly uploaded to the database and the images also are copied correctly in the folder.
But i can't see the image in the page.

Comment: echo('<img src="');echo($img_masc); echo('" width="250px" border-radius="1000px"/> '); 
//$img_masc it's the address where the image is.

Comment: @Valeria try echo '<img src=".$img_masc.">';

Comment: It didn't work, but appear a broken little image, but shouldn't show that.

Comment: @Valeria using console just check whther you are getting the image name. Print `$img_masc` and see whats printing on this variable. Debug step by step

Comment: I already did that and prints: "c:/wamp/www/Perf_Masc/image.jpg" but i dont know why dont show the imagen if looks good. I think dont find the route por i dont know.

Comment: @Valeria inside image src if you pass like c:/wamp/www/Perf_Masc/image.jpg it wont work. Inside image src it should be like <img src="http://localhost/Perf_Masc/image.jpg">

Comment: I try with  <img src="localhost/Perf_Masc/image.jpg"> and doesnt work. D:
but with <img src="../Perf_Masc/image.jpg"> does work.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

Change your forward slash to a back slash.

First define these

```
//Define back slash so that you can use it anywhere later
defined("DS") ? null : define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
// Define your website siteroot
defined("SITE_ROOT") ? null : define("SITE_ROOT", "C:".DS."wamp".DS."www".DS."your_website");
```

Now move your files

```
$file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_upload_to=SITE_ROOT . DS . "Perf_Masc";

move_uploaded_files($file_tmp, $file_upload_to . DS . $file_name);
```

If you have a hard time defining the root of your website, you can create a php file in your root directory and then `echo __DIR__` for PHP 5.3 or later, for earlier versions use `echo dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507